# side by side table overlap

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

my side by side table overlap, and I can't manage to adjust their sizes. Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

[image: croppedImage]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{filter window size}
\label{tab:config_filternum}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{| m{3cm} | m{4.3cm} | c |} 
 \hline
 number of entity filter (size 1) & number of context filters (size 2, size 3,
 size 4) & Accuracy\\ [2ex] 
 \hline
    32  &  32  ,  32  ,  32  &  0.835 \\[0.5ex]
    \hline
    32  &  64  ,  64  ,  64  &  0.821 \\[0.5ex]
    \hline
    \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\quad
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{| m{3cm} | m{4.3cm} | c |} 
 \hline
 number of entity filter (size 1) & number of context filters (size 2, size 3,
 size4) & Accuracy\\ [2ex] 
 \hline
512  &  32  ,  32  ,  32  &  0.910 \\[0.5ex]
\hline
512  &  64  ,  64  ,  64  &  0.922 \\[0.5ex]
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you don't need `minipage`, an example of solution follows with also a suggestion of mine to improve the look of your tables (and I think there's more to improve about the column headers).

I have also modified the caption set up to put some spaces after it.

EDIT: as suggested, I've modified my code to add raggedright alignment (even if Bernard has already given the best solutions).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=above, belowskip=4pt}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{filter window size}
\label{tab:config_filternum}
 \begin{tabularx}{.5\textwidth}{| X | X | c |} 
 \hline
 number of entity filter (size 1) & number of context filters (size 2, size 3,
 size 4) & Accuracy\\ [2ex] 
 \hline
    32  &  32  ,  32  ,  32  &  0.835 \\ [0.5ex]
    \hline
    32  &  64  ,  64  ,  64  &  0.821 \\ [0.5ex]
    \hline
    \hline
 \end{tabularx}
 \quad
\begin{tabularx}{.5\textwidth}{| X | X | c |} 
 \hline
 number of entity filter (size 1) & number of context filters (size 2, size 3,
 size 4) & Accuracy\\ [2ex] 
 \hline
512  &  32  ,  32  ,  32  &  0.910 \\[0.5ex]
\hline
512  &  64  ,  64  ,  64  &  0.922 \\[0.5ex]
\hline
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

but this is my suggestion:
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{filter window size }
    \label{tab:2filternum}
    \small
    \begin{tabularx}{.5\textwidth}{RRc} 
        \toprule
        Number of entity filter (size 1) & Number of context filters (size 2, size 3,
        size 4) & Accuracy\\ 
        \midrule
        32  &  32  ,  32  ,  32  &  0.835 \\ 
        32  &  64  ,  64  ,  64  &  0.821 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \quad
    \begin{tabularx}{.5\textwidth}{RRc} 
        \toprule
        Number of entity filter (size 1) & Number of context filters (size 2, size 3,
        size 4) & Accuracy\\ 
        \midrule
        512  &  32  ,  32  ,  32  &  0.910 \\
        512  &  64  ,  64  ,  64  &  0.922 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Make the columns at the lower table `\raggedright`. I guess it will look better.

Comment: Or maybe `\RaggedRight`.

Answer (score 3):

Here are 3 other solutions, with a simple `tabular`, based on the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks in column heads:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}%
 \usepackage{xspace, array}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, makecell,  cellspace}
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lc}

\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\newcommand\No{N\textsuperscript{o}\xspace}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]
  \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}\small
  \caption{filter window size}
  \label{tab:config_filternum}
  \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{Sc|}}
    \hline
    \thead{\No of entity  \\ filter (size 1)} &\thead{\No  of context filters\\ (size 2, size 3,  size 4)} &\thead{Accuracy}\\
    \hline
    32                   & 32 , 32 , 32 & 0.835 \\
    \hline
    32                   & 64 , 64 , 64 & 0.821 \\
    \hline
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{Sc|}}
    \hline
    \thead{\No  of entity  \\ filter (size 1)} &\thead{\No of context filters\\ (size 2, size 3,  size 4)} & \thead{Accuracy}\\
    \hline
    512                   & 32 , 32 , 32 & 0.910 \\
    \hline
    512                   & 64 , 64 , 64 & 0.922 \\
    \hline
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[htbp]
  \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}\small
  \caption{filter window size}
  \label{tab:config_filternum}
  \begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}}
    \toprule
    \thead{\No of entity  \\ filter (size 1)} &\thead{\No  of context filters\\ (size 2, size 3,  size 4)} &\thead{Accuracy}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    32                   & 32 , 32 , 32 & 0.835 \\
    \addlinespace
    32                   & 64 , 64 , 64 & 0.821 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}}
    \toprule
    \thead{\No  of entity  \\ filter (size 1)} &\thead{\No of context filters\\ (size 2, size 3,  size 4)} & \thead{Accuracy}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    512                   & 32 , 32 , 32 & 0.910 \\
    \addlinespace
    512                   & 64 , 64 , 64 & 0.922 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}\small
  \caption{filter window size}
  \label{tab:config_filternum}
  \begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}}
    \toprule
    \addlinespace[0pt]
    \cmidrule{1-3}
    \thead{\No of entity  \\ filter (size 1)} &\thead{\No  of context filters\\ (size 2, size 3,  size 4)} &\thead{Accuracy}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    32                   & 32 , 32 , 32 & 0.835 \\
    \addlinespace
    32                   & 64 , 64 , 64 & 0.821 \\
    \cmidrule{1-3}
    \addlinespace[-2.7pt]
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}}
    \toprule
    \addlinespace[0pt]
    \cmidrule{1-3}
    \thead{\No  of entity  \\ filter (size 1)} &\thead{\No of context filters\\ (size 2, size 3,  size 4)} & \thead{Accuracy}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    512                   & 32 , 32 , 32 & 0.910 \\
    \addlinespace
    512                   & 64 , 64 , 64 & 0.922 \\
    \cmidrule{1-3}
    \addlinespace[-2.7pt]
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]